# Developing an Android library but its dependencies are not automatically downloaded by the dependent app

Tags: android, gradle-dependencies

I am developing an Android library, which has some dependencies to other library:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.1.0'
    implementation 'no.nordicsemi.android:dfu:2.0.2'
    implementation 'no.nordicsemi.android.support.v18:scanner:1.6.0'
    implementation 'no.nordicsemi.android:ble:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.0'
}
```

Then I build a `.aar` with gradle task `assembleRelease` or `.jar` with gradle task `createFullJarRelease`.

When I develop an App that use this library by
`implementation files("libs/MyLibrary.aar")` or
`implementation files("libs/MyLibrary.jar")` , both have the same issue,

I have to add those dependencies to my app's build.gradle too, otherwise I get `NoClassDefFoundError` for the class coming from those dependencies. I don't think this is the right way since no other libraries would require an app to add the library's dependencies to the app's dependencies. What am I missing?

Comment: You want a "fat aar" https://github.com/kezong/fat-aar-android read more here: https://handstandsam.com/2018/07/13/why-we-need-fat-aars-for-android-libraries/

Comment: @Blundell Thanks for the useful resources. Seems pretty fit my use case.

Answer (score 1):

In your library, replace

```
implementation
```

by

```
api
```

to share libraries with your app. You will no longer need to add the same librairies in your app